# Keycloak Event Listener invoke Spring Boot Endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, security, events, keycloak, listener

I have a Keycloak instance in which i created an EventListener (Provider & ProviderFactory) that responds to register events.
But now I want this EventListener to call an endpoint in my SpringBoot app which is secured by this Keycloak instance (as client).
For this I can simply send a Http request from inside the EventListenerProvider. However, I am wondering how I can secure the endpoint so that only this Keycloak event listener can access the endpoint.

Can Keycloak authenticate itself for a client endpoint ???

Maybe u guys have an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like other apps that calls each other using a token they got from Keycloak. You can define a client for your even listener in Keycloak realm (or for your Keycloak as a whole in case it may want to call other endpoints in future). Then before making a call to your Spring endpoint, you get a token from Keycloak via the client-id/client-secret (by calling the `/token` endpoint of your realm) and put it as the `Authorization` header in your request.

Comment: just a perfect answer thank you vmuch !